# How to capture and upload a video using jquery and laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I would like to give access to user to record a video from application and user can upload that after preview. After some try and I am able to record and download a video. But I am not sure how can I upload that on server?

I have referred this code - [link](https://mido22.github.io/MediaRecorder-sample/)

HTML -

```
<div id='gUMArea'>
        <div class="videoRadio">
            <input type="radio" name="media" value="video" checked id='mediaVideo'>Video
            <input type="radio" name="media" value="audio">audio
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id='gUMbtn'>Request Stream</button>
    </div>
    <div id='btns'>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id='start'>Start</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id='stop'>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <!-- <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video> -->
    <form id="video">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="testVideo">
        <input type="file" name="video" id="uploadVideo" value="">
        <div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled" id='ul'></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-btn">
            <a href="/list-your-product?step=2&uniqueId={{$data[0]->uniqueId}}" class="btn btn-success w-100">Back</a>
            <button class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit" id="front-dropzone-btn">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My js code -

```
'use strict'

// var video = document.getElementById('video');

// // Get access to the camera!
// if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
//     // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
//     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
//         //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
//         video.srcObject = stream;
//         video.play();
//     });
// }

let log = console.log.bind(console),
  id = val => document.getElementById(val),
  ul = id('ul'),
  gUMbtn = id('gUMbtn'),
  start = id('start'),
  stop = id('stop'),
  uploadVideo = id('uploadVideo'),
  stream,
  recorder,
  counter=1,
  chunks,
  media;


gUMbtn.onclick = e => {
  let mv = id('mediaVideo'),
      mediaOptions = {
        video: {
          tag: 'video',
          type: 'video/webm',
          ext: '.mp4',
          gUM: {video: true, audio: true}
        },
        audio: {
          tag: 'audio',
          type: 'audio/ogg',
          ext: '.ogg',
          gUM: {audio: true}
        }
      };
  media = mv.checked ? mediaOptions.video : mediaOptions.audio;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(media.gUM).then(_stream => {
    stream = _stream;
    // video.srcObject = stream;
    // video.play();
    id('gUMArea').style.display = 'none';
    id('btns').style.display = 'inherit';
    start.removeAttribute('disabled');
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
      chunks.push(e.data);
      if(recorder.state == 'inactive')  makeLink();
    };
    log('got media successfully');
  }).catch(log);
}

start.onclick = e => {
  start.disabled = true;
  stop.removeAttribute('disabled');
  chunks=[];
  recorder.start();
}


stop.onclick = e => {
  stop.disabled = true;
  recorder.stop();
  start.removeAttribute('disabled');
}

function makeLink(){
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
    , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    , li = document.createElement('li')
    , mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
    , hf = document.createElement('a')
  ;
  mt.controls = true;
  mt.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = `${counter++}${media.ext}`;
  hf.innerHTML = `donwload ${hf.download}`;
  li.appendChild(mt);
  li.appendChild(hf);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  console.log(hf.download);
  console.log(uploadVideo.value);
  uploadVideo.value = hf.download;
}
```

It will great if someone can help me to understand how to upload on server.

Also, by using this js code user can not see himself/herself while recording. How can I activate that?

[image]

Comment: you need to `ssl` setup to test this in local

Comment: Ok. I will setup ssl. But how can I pass this recorded video to controller and upload?

Comment: can you check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your [reference website](https://mido22.github.io/MediaRecorder-sample/)

your are getting blob data of video steam so you can send that to controller via ajax

### web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/save', function (Request $request) {
    $path =  \Storage::disk('public')->put('videos',$request->video);
    $url = \Storage::disk('public')->url($path);
    return $url;
});
```

### welcome.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MediaRecorder API - Sample</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="WebRTC getUserMedia MediaRecorder API">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <style>
      button{
        margin: 10px 5px;
      }
      li{
        margin: 10px;
      }
      body{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
      #btns{
        display: none;
      }
      h1{
        margin: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> MediaRecorder API example</h1>

    <p> For now it is supported only in Firefox(v25+) and Chrome(v47+)</p>
    <div id='gUMArea'>
      <div>
      Record:
        <input type="radio" name="media" value="video" checked id='mediaVideo'>Video
        <input type="radio" name="media" value="audio">audio
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default"  id='gUMbtn'>Request Stream</button>
    </div>
    <div id='btns'>
      <button  class="btn btn-default" id='start'>Start</button>
      <button  class="btn btn-default" id='stop'>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul  class="list-unstyled" id='ul'></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/video.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### video.js

```js
'use strict'

let log = console.log.bind(console),
  id = val => document.getElementById(val),
  ul = id('ul'),
  gUMbtn = id('gUMbtn'),
  start = id('start'),
  stop = id('stop'),
  stream,
  recorder,
  counter=1,
  chunks,
  media;


gUMbtn.onclick = e => {
  let mv = id('mediaVideo'),
      mediaOptions = {
        video: {
          tag: 'video',
          type: 'video/webm',
          ext: '.mp4',
          gUM: {video: true, audio: true}
        },
        audio: {
          tag: 'audio',
          type: 'audio/ogg',
          ext: '.ogg',
          gUM: {audio: true}
        }
      };
  media = mv.checked ? mediaOptions.video : mediaOptions.audio;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(media.gUM).then(_stream => {
    stream = _stream;
    id('gUMArea').style.display = 'none';
    id('btns').style.display = 'inherit';
    start.removeAttribute('disabled');
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
      chunks.push(e.data);
      if(recorder.state == 'inactive')  makeLink();
    };
    log('got media successfully');
  }).catch(log);
}

start.onclick = e => {
  start.disabled = true;
  stop.removeAttribute('disabled');
  chunks=[];
  recorder.start();
}


stop.onclick = e => {
  stop.disabled = true;
  recorder.stop();
  start.removeAttribute('disabled');
}



function makeLink(){
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
    , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    , li = document.createElement('li')
    , mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
    , hf = document.createElement('a')
  ;
  mt.controls = true;
  mt.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = `${counter++}${media.ext}`;
  hf.innerHTML = `donwload ${hf.download}`;
  li.appendChild(mt);
  li.appendChild(hf);
  ul.appendChild(li);


  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('_token',  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  formData.append('video', blob);
  fetch('/save', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {});
}
```

> Here i sending  **blob** data to server and store in storage

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I got error - Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$video in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Moana Digital\GiveAway\routes\web.php

Comment: I have debug js and getting form data in console.log. Please check updated question with image for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for this help. Video is there in storage. But it is uploading blank video.

Comment: @SaurabhGupte add 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;